# External Php class in Yii?

Tags: class, yii, external

Hello I need to use evalmath.class.php within a Yii application. How can I include it from my controller?

Something like this:

```
public function actionFormulas() {
    include('models/evalmath.class.php');
    $m = new EvalMath;
    ...
}
```

But the above code does not work. How can I include an external class within a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, to use include/require you probably need to add some path info with `dirname(__FILE__).'/../models/...'` or similar, but to do it within the Yii framework, you would first create an alias (usually in your main config file) with [setPathOfAlias](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#setPathOfAlias-detail) :

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('evalmath', $evalmath_path);
```

Then you can use [Yii::import](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#import-detail) like so:

```
Yii::import('evalmath', true);
```

and proceed as you were:

```
$m = new EvalMath();
..etc...
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. EvalMath is correctly included. But now, I got another problem. Inside Yii, operations with parentheses don't work, while outside they do. Even the simple $m->evaluate('(2+2)'); breaks the program.

Comment: Solved but I don't know why that happens. Now the result has nothing when pulling the formula from the database. You can have a look to my code if you want at https://github.com/ivantxo/Yii-MathEval/blob/master/matheval/protected/controllers/CalcController.php. The function is actionFormulas, and you will need to create a database in mysql called matheval, there is a sql script at the root of the repository. matheval.sql. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        Yii::import('application.controllers.back.ConsolidateController'); // ConsolidateController is another controller in back controller folder
        echo ConsolidateController::test(); // test is action in ConsolidateController
```